# Evaluating Math.tan(Math.acos(0d))

Tags: java, math

Shouldn't the following statement hold?

```
assertTrue(Double.isNaN(Math.tan(Math.acos(0d))));
```

But instead of `Double.NaN` Java returns

```
6.123233995736766 * 10^-17
```

on my 64-bit box.

**EDIT:** 
This was a Copy and Paste error. In fact Java returns `1.633123935319537E16`

I'm aware that this is because of the floating point representation, but i was under the impression that those undefined values of the tangent function would get the same treatment as e.g. `Math.sqrt(-1d)` but I guess in this case java.lang.Math just checks if the argument is positive before evaluating.

Comment: It *shouldn't* be `NaN` but instead a really large number (positive infinity). In fact, I'm getting `1.633123935319537E16`.

Comment: I wouldn't expect NaN due to rounding errors, but I wouldn't expect almost-zero either.

Comment: In Javascript, I'm getting `16331778728383844`

Comment: Opps yes, copied wrong there i get `1.633123935319537E16` as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get something different.

```
System.out.println(Math.tan(Math.acos(0d)));
// and the tan for the next representable value.
System.out.println(Math.tan(Math.acos(0d) + Math.ulp(Math.acos(0d))));
```

prints

```
1.633123935319537E16
-6.218431163823738E15
```

A 64-bit floating point cannot represent PI/2 exactly (it has an infinite number of digits) it represents a number close to this value and the tan() of this value is finite.